# simplexml_load_file($feedURL) returns bool(false) even that the RSS works

Tags: php, youtube, rss, simplexml

I am trying to make a simple widget that loads a youtube rss feed and shows the few first videos.

The problem is that even the RSS adress is correct it allways dumps false

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ninpetit/uploads?alt=rss&v=2';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
var_dump($sxml); /* output:  bool(false)  */
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any alternative to `simplexml_load_file`?

PS: This code is being executed in a shared server

EDIT

I successfully getting the data vía curl, but the simplexml_load_file will return false if I pass the $data

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ninpetit/uploads?alt=rss&v=2';
$ch = curl_init($feedURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data.'<br>'; /* shows data!! */
sxml = simplexml_load_file($data); /*Also false*/
```

Comment: Is is possible that the system doesn't allow URL fopen? Check the value of the ini setting `allow_url_fopen`. Also, try to just get the contents of the feed using `file_get_contents` to see if it loads that way.

Comment: Try [`libxml_get_errors`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php) and see what the error message says.

Comment: @dleiftah Yes, file_get_contents returns the same. I have only a folder /htdocs/ and there is no php.ini in there (or in the root folder)

Comment: `simplexml_load_file` won't accept your `$data`. It's named `load_file` for a reason

Comment: Now that you have the data in a string, you can use `simplexml_load_string($data)` ... that should get you going ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have xml data in your $data string, you can easily parse it using `simplexml_load_string()` function.